# Is admin url stored in any table associated with order?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, database, orders, magento-1

I'm wondering **if custom admin url is stored in any table associate with orders in database**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only place you can find the admin URL is under `core_config_data` and this table is not associated with any entity data (including orders).

According to the comment, it seems like the entry you're referring to are **coming from an RMA extension**.

Comment: I'm aware about "core_config_data". Curiously I was looking for admin path in db tables and encountered sales_creditmemo data in db keeps track of admin url.

Comment: @Zinat in which column ?

Comment: Actually I searched the admin url string in sql file.  <a href=\"http://www.mydomain/index.php/customadminpath/sales_order/view/order_id/169731/key/92c3ff6519aebda24fea88205ebfb0c2/\">...12224,1906,'2016-07-12 14:03:19','Rma status change to requested'),(12225,1906,'2016-07-12 14:03:27','Rma status change to product_return_accepted'),(12226,1906,'2016-07-12 14:03:27','Customer notified for status Tuotteen palautus hyväksytty'),(1227,1857,'2016-07-12 14:23:31','<a href=\"http://www.mydomain/index.php/customadminpath/sales_creditmemo/view/creditmemo_id/../key/.../\">Credit memo #28 created</a>')

Comment: And I'm looking for the table.

Comment: @Zinat pretty sure that comes from an RMA extension and is not Magento out of the box

Comment: @Zinat done I hope it helped